# Exclude a single field from migration

Tags: python, django, orm

My model maps a table from existing database. I have a field referencing to another table, but in a source table there is no foreign key constraint. While there is `managed=False` flag in a `Meta`, class everything is all right, but I wanted to add a field in a model, so I need to remove this flag. From this moment I get an error as below:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "<referencing_column_id>" of relation "<relation_name>" already exists
```

I think solution would be setting `managed=False` flag for a single field. Is it actually a solution for this problem? If not, is there another way?